# keep each value in the biggest group - R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have df with groups A,B,C,D
for each group there is rank  A 1 the higher, B , c then D the lowest.

in each group, there is Names and ID I need to keep for each one the highest ranks only.

```
ID | Name | Group
101| Jon  | A
101| Jon  | C
103| Tom  | B
103| Tom  | D
103| Tom  | C
```

the output needs like that

```
ID | Name | Group
101| Jon  | A
103| Tom  | B
```

What is the best way to do it using Tidyverse R

Thanks

I already use distinct to keep one value for each ID, I used case_when to keep in each group. but I now want to keep only the higher rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
 arrange(ID, Name, factor(Group, levels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))) %>%
 distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

-output

```
   ID Name Group
1 101  Jon     A
2 103  Tom     B
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(101, 101, 103, 103, 103), Name = c("Jon", 
"Jon", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom"), Group = c("A", "C", "B", "D", "C"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```